# xlsx file corrupted while downloading with the file-saver npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesaver.js, js-xlsx

I am having a problem in downloading a `xlsx` file. My excel file is generated with [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). I have to add some authorization headers to verify the incoming requests on the server. For this reason, I can not just simply open the link in a new window from my client-side. For testing purpose, I try to download the file by directly hitting the browser link of my API endpoint (of course by removing the authorization middleware temporarily). The browser downloads the file without any problem or corruption. Unfortunately, this is not the case with the client-side download functionality while using [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) through [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) get request.

My snippet from the backend code where I am sending the response is:

```
 //..... Some code for writing the workBook

 const workBookOutput = xlsx.write(workBook, {
      bookType: 'xlsx',
      type: 'buffer'
    });
 const xlsxFileBuffer = Buffer.from(workBookOutput);

 // res is express HTTP response object
 res.set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=excel-export.xlsx');

 res.status(200).send(xlsxFileBuffer);
```

The part of my client-side code is:

```
const headers = {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: 'application/json'
};

// here I add some real jwt token in my code, not the dummy that I have below
headers.authorization = `bearer asklndashduwkhd2oo832uejh32oihjdoasincas`;

const options = {
         'get',
          'https://myURLToAPi/api',
          headers,
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }
const response = await axios(options);

//fileSaver is required above in file 

fileSaver.saveAs(
  new Blob([response.data], {
    type:
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  }),
  'excel.xlsx'
);
```

I still only get the corrupted file. I have tried multiple options on server and client-side both, nevertheless, the downloaded file always comes as corrupted. I have tried not making another `Buffer.from` after getting my `workbookOutput` still nothing has changed. Can someone help me in this regard? Am I missing something?

This is the picture of what I get for corrupt download if I try to open it.

[image]

Comment: Compare the working and corrupt files, perhaps in a hex editor. What is the difference? (Note that even an extra zero byte at the end will upset it.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton First and the weird difference is the size. Corrupted downloads are 3 times the size of non-corrupted ones.

Comment: Has something strange happened to it, like base-64 encoding?

Comment: I am actually not encoding it to base-64 on the client-side or server. Rather making whatever I receive as a blob and then passing to saveAs function with the content type. I am not sure what is causing problems.

Comment: You will have to look at it more closely. Are the first few bytes correct? Is it the same data repeated three times?

Comment: 6 months later...any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - I was generating Excel in Django, getting bytes then querying it using Axios. The Excel produced with FileSaver was corrupted, and, just like @Seeker mentioned, it was twice the size.

However I could get a normal file when testing in Postman. What solved my problem was setting

```
responseType: 'blob'
```

in axios options.